# Issues with a dropdown sticky navbar

Tags: html, css, dropdown, navbar, sticky

I've been working on this for hours and I can't figure out why it doesn't work,

I've built a navbar that sticks at the top of the page with five mains options in it and when an option is hovered, other options related drop down under the hovered option.

The thing is that it works well in most cases but when it comes to other elements like images, videos or audios, the navbar doesn't display over that element and it becomes impossible to click on it or on the dropdowned elements.

I'm a beginner so I'm not sure if I miss something obvious but let me know if I do ;)

Also, sorry for the English mistakes, I'm trying my best :D

```css
#navbar-container {
  position: fixed;
}

#navbar-principale {
  background: #4e6eff;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-principale-option {
  width: 20vw;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.navbar-principale-option:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}

.navbar-principale-option a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 20vw;
  padding: 1vh 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-principale-option:hover {
  background: #3a56d3;
}

.navbar-principale-option:hover .navbar-selection {
  visibility: visible;
}

.navbar-selection {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: #4e6eff;
  width: calc(20vw + 2px);
  margin-left: -2px;
  text-transform: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 10;
}

.navbar-selection-option:hover {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #3a56d3;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-selection-option:last-child a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.videos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-container">
  <ul id="navbar-principale">
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
      <a href="#top">Option 0</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
      <a href="#membres-selection">Option 1</a>
      <div class="navbar-selection">
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#membres-officiels">
            <p>Option 1-1</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#membres-externes">
            <p>Option 1-2</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
      <a href="#voyages">Option 2</a>
      <div class="navbar-selection">
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#italie2019">
            <p>Option 2-1</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#bretagne2020">
            <p>Option 2-2</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#bretagne2021">
            <p>Option 2-3</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
      <a href="#histoire">Option 3</a>
      <div class="navbar-selection">
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#df-culte">
            <p>Option 3-1</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#df-memes">
            <p>Option 3-2</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
      <a href="#bonus">Option 4</a>
      <div class="navbar-selection">
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#musiques">
            <p>Option 4-1</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#covers">
            <p>Option 4-2</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-selection-option">
          <a href="#bonus-autres">
            <p>Option 4-3</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="videos">
  <video controls="controls" width="567px" height="280">
        <source id="landing-video">
    </video>
  <video controls="controls" width="567px" height="280px">
        <source id="landing-video">
    </video>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<audio controls>
    <source type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p> to create some space to scroll </p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding `z-index` to `#navbar-container`.
`.videos` is same level with `#navbar-container`, but there's no `z-index` property in `#navbar-container`, so it's behind the `.videos` element.
`z-index` to sublevel element doesn't work to super leveled elements.

```css
#navbar-container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
}
#navbar-principale {
  background: #4e6eff;
  font-size: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.navbar-principale-option {
  width: 20vw;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}
.navbar-principale-option:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
.navbar-principale-option a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 20vw;
  padding: 1vh 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-principale-option:hover {
  background: #3a56d3;
}
.navbar-principale-option:hover .navbar-selection {
  visibility: visible;
}
.navbar-selection {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background: #4e6eff;
  width: calc(20vw + 2px);
  margin-left: -2px;
  text-transform: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  z-index: 10;
}
.navbar-selection-option:hover {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #3a56d3;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.navbar-selection-option:last-child a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.videos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar-container">
<ul id="navbar-principale">
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
        <a href="#top">Option 0</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
        <a href="#membres-selection">Option 1</a>
        <div class="navbar-selection">
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#membres-officiels">
                    <p>Option 1-1</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#membres-externes">
                    <p>Option 1-2</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
        <a href="#voyages">Option 2</a>
        <div class="navbar-selection">
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#italie2019">
                    <p>Option 2-1</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#bretagne2020">
                    <p>Option 2-2</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#bretagne2021">
                    <p>Option 2-3</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
        <a href="#histoire">Option 3</a>
        <div class="navbar-selection">
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#df-culte">
                    <p>Option 3-1</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#df-memes">
                    <p>Option 3-2</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-principale-option">
        <a href="#bonus">Option 4</a>
        <div class="navbar-selection">
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#musiques">
                    <p>Option 4-1</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#covers">
                    <p>Option 4-2</p>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-selection-option">
                <a href="#bonus-autres">
                    <p>Option 4-3</p>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="videos">
    <video controls="controls" width="567px" height="280">
        <source id="landing-video">
    </video>
    <video controls="controls" width="567px" height="280px">
        <source id="landing-video">
    </video>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<audio controls>
    <source type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p> to create some space to scroll </p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works exactly as I wanted it to ;)

Comment: Did you know? [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)